# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException for parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working in spring mvc project.

I am able to run my project in my local without any issues. I did a page for file upload using controller.

While I used this with production, I am not able to get the results and getting the error

```
"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'userId' is not present
```

my code : (I am getting this user Id in upload screen)

```
@Resource
private UserService userService;


@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Long userId = userService.getLoggedInUser(request).getId();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadmain);
    modelAndView.addObject("userId", userId);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

upload jsp

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.htm">
    File to upload: 
    <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 

    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${userId}"><br /> <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

FileUploadController

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @Resource
    private CollectionsRepository collectionsRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
            return "You can upload a file by posting to this same URL.";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/upload.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    String filePath = "/home/ubuntu/analyzer/LOS/";
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    File newFile = new File(filePath+""+file.getOriginalFilename());
                    BufferedOutputStream stream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();

                    List<BankStatementError> errorList = new ArrayList<BankStatementError>();

                    Excelsheetreader esr = new Excelsheetreader();
                    List<String> listaddSN = esr.GetCalculation(Long.parseLong(userId), filePath+""+file.getOriginalFilename());

                    newFile.delete();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listaddSN.size(); i++) {
                        String bank = listaddSN.get(i);
                        BankStatementError error = collectionsRepository.getErrorByBank(bank);
                        errorList.add(error);
                    }

                    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadsuccess);
                    modelAndView.addObject("errorList", errorList);
                    return modelAndView;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadexecption);
                    return modelAndView;
                }
            } else {
                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(UploadDocView.uploadempty);
                return modelAndView;
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is userId comes as null, which is getting for upload screen, I think. But not sure. Can anyone point me a right way in this?

Comment: Do you require the user-id for file-upload so file can be associated to the user? If yes, I presume the user must be logged in. Can't you get the user-id of the currently logged in user? Spring-security can do that...

Comment: Yes, this userId has to be stored in next process, which was loggedIn user. I am able to bring that userId and that is working fine in my local.. but dono whats the problem in production

Comment: So, are you trying to tell me that when the user uploads something, then the user is logged-in? Also, this is not a very good idea to pass such values for authenticated users, and much less relying on them.

Comment: Than how may we get that as reliable?

Comment: If you are using Spring, and you don't have any authentication mechanism, then use Spring-Security. With which you will be able to get the currently logged in user. You can directly get the user-id from that. Also, it can be used for access-control management, securing your methods, password encryption and much more. Ofcourse you need to set it up.